# Склонение словосочетания «синяя речка»

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, согласование, словосочетания

*За син**ей** речк**ою*** — будет ли ошибкой различие окончаний прилагательного и существительного? Или необходимо (лучше) так: *за син**ею** речк**ою**,
за син**ей** речк**ой***?

Если это ошибка, как она объясняется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибки как таковой, думаю, здесь нет, но вне художественного текста подобное скорее всего будет воспринято как стилистическая шероховатость. И дело даже не в том, что формы окончания разные, просто полная форма окончания творительного падежа прилагательного  женского рода (син**ею**) в современном языке вообще воспринимается как устаревшая. В отношении же существительных того же рода и падежа (рек**ою**) имеет место тот же процесс, но более медленный, поэтому даже в строгих текстах исключить появление подобных сочетаний нельзя.

В художественном же, особенно в поэтическом, тексте - сколько угодно.

*За синею рекой,

Где хмельные росы,

Где по небу мукой

Звезд холодных россыпь...*

Георгий Бронштейн "За синею рекой"

Answer (score 3):

[Речка](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) — ре́чкой, ре́чкою (Т. п., ж. р.);
[синяя](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) — си́ней, си́нею (Т. п., ж. р.).

Обычно при таком расположении слов считается, что первый вариант общеупотребительный, а второй — допустимый (не ошибочный).
**Синей речкой** — это нейтральный вариант словосочетания, все остальные — возможные, нет здесь ошибки.

[Упражнение 49](https://budu5.com/gdztask/view/2639)
1. *На зорьке утренней над **речкой быстрою** умылась яблоня **росою чистою*** (Я. Шведов).
2. *А рядом с ново зеленью лепечут песню новую и липа бледнолистая и белая берёзонька с **зелёною косой*** (Н. Некрасов).

Вот слова из советской песни ["Наташа"](https://teksty-pesenok.ru/rus-via-rovesniki/tekst-pesni-natasha/1764974/) (можно послушать):
*Живет **за речкой синею**, за тихою долиною Наташа.*

*Что это за утро! Серебряный иней

На зелени луга лежит;

Камыш пожелтевший **над речкою синей

Сквозною оградой** стоит.*
. . .
*У осени поздней, **порою печальной**,

Есть чудные краски свои,

Как есть своя прелесть в улыбке прощальной,

В последнем объятье любви.*
И. С. Никитин. 19 октября